# C# SDK to Extract Image within Shape in PDF

Tags: pdf, c#, sdk

I read a lot of books in PDF format and highlight them. I then extract all the highlights and use them to study.

I would like to be able to do this with images too - but I don't just want to extract all the images - I want to extract the specific portion that I've drawn a rectangle around. In the sample image that I made, below, I'd like to just extract the chunk of code within the red rectangle - to a JPG or stream or something I can manipulate in the study software I'm writing.

Does anyone know of an SDK that allows this? It seems I should be able to identify the rectangles in the PDF file and their coordinates - and then extract an image based on those coordinates - but I've not been able to find anyone doing this. Worst case, how can I identify an image I've drawn a rectangle around and extract the image beneath it - in this case the entire Visual Studio image?

I'm using the SyncFusion PDF solution to extract the highlighting. I've tinkered with ITextSharp. It's possible one of these may do it - but I haven't figured out how (yet).

Thanks.

P.S. Page is from an excellent book called "The C# Player's Guide" by RB Whitaker

[image]

Comment: Don't have enough rep to comment, so I'll ask for details here: 1. How exactly do you draw the "highlight" rectangle on the image? 2. Can you share a small PDF file with a highlighted image?

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a rectangular region from an image using Leadtools. As a disclaimer, I work for LEAD Technologies that develops this toolkit. If you are displaying the image in an ImageViewer, you can use the ImageVeiwerAddRegionInteractiveMode to allow the user to select a region with their mouse. You can then copy the region to a second imageViewer using the following code, which is set in the WinForms Form constructor:

```
var regionInteractiveMode = new ImageViewerAddRegionInteractiveMode
{
    Shape = ImageViewerRubberBandShape.Rectangle,
};

regionInteractiveMode.WorkCompleted += (s, e) =>
    {
        if (imageViewer.Floater != null)
    {
        imageViewer2.Image = imageViewer.Floater.Clone();
        imageViewer.Floater.MakeRegionEmpty();
        var region = imageViewer2.Image.GetRegion(null);
        imageViewer2.Image.MakeRegionEmpty();
        imageViewer2.Image.SetRegion(null, region, RasterRegionCombineMode.SetNot);
        new FillCommand(RasterColor.White).Run(imageViewer2.Image);
        imageViewer2.Image.MakeRegionEmpty();
    }
};

imageViewer.InteractiveModes.BeginUpdate();
imageViewer.InteractiveModes.Add(regionInteractiveMode);
imageViewer.InteractiveModes.EndUpdate();
```

You should get a result similar to this:
[image: Sample application]